# Read python script in another python script as text

Tags: python

I'd like to open python script in another python script and read the content in text format. How can I do that?

Trying to open file with construction `with open('file.py')` gets me the following output:

> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='script.py' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
with open('file.py') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Or use the `inspect` module:

```
import inspect
inspect.getsource(__import__('file'))
```

Using `inspect.getsource` would run the file though.

Comment: Would not `__import__` cause execution?

Comment: @Daweo True, clarified that.